# Visual Studio Xamarin CarouselPage Children autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, autocomplete

Sorry for newbe question. 
I use last Visual Studio 2015 on last WIndows 10 with last Xamarine.
I write follow code:

```
MainPage = new CarouselPage
{
    Children =
    {
        new LoginPage(),
        new MainGrid()
    }
};
```

In Children property I have several dosens autocomplete options, but not "Children".
Despite this fact the app successfuly built, deploy and run.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var carousel = new CarouselPage();    
carousel.Children.Add (new LoginPage());
carousel.Children.Add (new MainGrid());

MainPage = carousel;
```